# How long does it take for an AWS Certificate to update in a Cloudfront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-acm

I have an AWS Cloudfront distribution setup to use an ACM certificate.

After updating the certificate, it seems it is not updating yet the certificate the distribution is using.

I am guessing this is expected (similar to the update delay in the distribution), but can't find a note in the AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate-api-cli.html) regarding this delay.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=825995):

> We have typically seen 2.5-3 hour delays for propagation

Answer (score 1):

For me it has always been around 4 hours before Cloudfront sees the updated cert in ACM.

Be careful about how you check the cert that CF is providing. If you use a browser, the browser may be caching the older cert. For example, I went to my site using macOS Safari and it shows the old cert, 5 hours after updating. I tried Chrome and it shows the new cert.

I've found that using either cURL or this [Digicert help page](https://www.digicert.com/help/) provides current, uncached, results.